# is there another way to fetch details from API?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, react-router-dom

I am trying to fetch data using fetch function but somehow the request is not being processes

```
import React,{useState,useEffect} from 'react'
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom'

const NotePage = () => {
    let noteId = useParams()
    let [note,setNote]=useState([])

    useEffect=( () => {
        getNote()

    },[noteId])

    let getNote=async()=>{
        #this function is not being processed
        let response = await fetch(`/api/notes/${noteId}/`)
        let data= await response.json()
        console.log("Data:",data)
        setNote(data)

    }

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Single {note}</h1>

        </div>
    )
}

export default NotePage
```

Output:
Single
Expected output:
Single data

Comment: Are you trying to deconstruct noteId from useparams? Cause noteId = useparams will give an object filled with all params

Comment: Yes Exactly and also it is showing error while returning

Answer (score 1):

You have to get noteId from params like this,

```
let { noteId } = useParams();
```

Answer (score 1):

you have not destructured the object which we get from useParams. Instead of writing `let noteId = useParams();` write `const {noteId} = useParams()` also you can remove the dependency from useEffect() as the **noteId** will not be updated unless your Params change, and if the params change the component will obviously re-render.

Comment: the id is being passed but still cant render the data on page

Comment: the get note function is not working i guess

Comment: the getnote( ) is not working because the noteId you provided is undefined. if you use detructuring while fetching params your noteId will have some value and it will fetch successfully as per the **noteId** (value in params).

Comment: Also remove the dependency and check console if there is an error or not.

Comment: const NotePage = () => {
    
    const {id} = useParams()
    let [note,setNote]=useState([])
    
    console.log(id)
    
    useEffect=( () => {
        getNote()

    },[])

    let getNote=async()=>{
        let response=await fetch(`/api/notes/${id}/`)
        // let response = await fetch(`/api/notes/${id}/`)

        let data= await response.json()
        console.log("Data:",data)
        console.log(response)
        setNote(data)

    }

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Single {note.body}</h1>

        </div>
    )
}

export default NotePage

Comment: i tried but still not able to fetch data

Comment: check if your api is giving responses on this link. if not then fix api.

Comment: otherwise mention your API.